# Homework Question :: Tried very hard :: Need Direction

Tags: sqlite

I have been stuck on this progressive question for more than 10 days now

Questions is :: Find all the actors that made more movies with Yash Chopra than any other director

Heres my attempt

```
SELECT pidsWhoDidMoviesWithYashChopra.pid,
            pidsWhoDidMoviesWithYashChopra.moviesWithYashChopra,
            pidsOfThoseWhoDidMoviesWithDirectors.moviesByAPID,
            pidsWhoDidMoviesWithYashChopra.countOfMoviesWithYashChopraByAPID,
            pidsOfThoseWhoDidMoviesWithDirectors.totalNumberOfMoviesByAPID
            FROM
            (
                SELECT TRIM(M_Cast.PID) AS pid, moviesByYashChopra.mDirectorMID AS moviesWithYashChopra, COUNT(moviesByYashChopra.mDirectorMID) AS countOfMoviesWithYashChopraByAPID
                FROM M_Cast
                JOIN
                (
                    SELECT TRIM(M_Director.MID) AS mDirectorMID
                    FROM
                    M_Director
                    WHERE TRIM(M_Director.PID) IN
                    (
                        SELECT TRIM(Person.PID) AS personPID
                        FROM
                        Person
                        WHERE Person.Name LIKE '%Yash Chopra%'
                    )
                ) AS moviesByYashChopra
                ON TRIM(M_Cast.MID) == moviesByYashChopra.mDirectorMID
                GROUP BY pid
            ) AS pidsWhoDidMoviesWithYashChopra
            JOIN
            (
                SELECT TRIM(M_Cast.PID) AS pid, TRIM(M_Cast.MID) AS moviesByAPID, COUNT(TRIM(M_Cast.MID)) AS totalNumberOfMoviesByAPID
                FROM M_Cast
                GROUP BY pid
            ) AS pidsOfThoseWhoDidMoviesWithDirectors
            ON pidsWhoDidMoviesWithYashChopra.pid == pidsOfThoseWhoDidMoviesWithDirectors.pid
            GROUP BY pidsWhoDidMoviesWithYashChopra.pid
```

And here's the output it produces

[image]

And here's the schema

[image]

Now where I require help is :: Ability to go ahead from here :: As in how do i dissect this part of the question "**than any other director.**" :: I think that's the tricky part

Any direction/hints will be helpful, Thanks...

Comment: What book, what tutorial about [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) did you read? Did you read *all* the documentation of [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/) ? Consider using it on the command line, and show some [mre] in your question (no images, just code ...)

Comment: Didn't read any book on sql..Just browsing around google and learning as it comes...

Comment: [This](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/) is an SQL tutorial. Take a few days to *read it carefully* then find others.

Comment: Read also the wikipage on [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), then read *more* and *again* SQL tutorials

Comment: Read also some [set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory) and some [relation algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_algebra) tutorial; they are *very relevant* in [relational databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database).

Answer (score 2):

You need to join `person` (for the actor's details) with `m_cast`, `movie`, `m_director` and `person` again (for the director's details) and `group by` actor and director to count the number of movies each actor made with each director.
Then use window functions `first_value()` to get the name of the director with whom the actor made the most movies and `lag()` to get the 2nd max number of movies (this is needed to filter out ties).
Enclose this query inside a CTE and then filter:

```
with cte as (
  select pa.pid, pa.name, count(*) counter,
         first_value(pd.name) over (partition by pa.pid, pa.name order by count(*) desc) max_dir_name,
         lag(count(*)) over (partition by pa.pid, pa.name order by count(*) desc) prev_counter 
  from person pa
  inner join m_cast c on c.pid = pa.pid
  inner join movie m on m.mid = c.mid
  inner join m_director d on d.mid = m.mid
  inner join person pd on pd.pid = d.pid
  group by pa.pid, pa.name, pd.name
)
select pid, name, counter
from cte
where max_dir_name = 'Yash Chopra' and coalesce(prev_counter, 0) < counter
```